# Missing data fields in Wikidata Query Service results despite items having these data

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to retrieve some municipalities from Wikidata using SPARQL but several items returned have much of their fields empty despite these items having these data. I do not understand what is wrong with the query below ([link to WQS](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fmun%20%3FmunLabel%20%3Fcoords%20%3FparentPlace%20%3Farea%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fmun%20p%3AP31%20%3FinstanceOf%20%23%20Get%20statement%20because%20we%20need%20this%20later%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FinstanceOf%20ps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3A279%2A%20wd%3AQ2039348.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fmun%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoords%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP131%20%3FparentPlace%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP2046%20%3Farea%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20MINUS%20%7B%20%3FinstanceOf%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendTime.%20%7D%20%23%20Don%27t%20show%20municipalities%20that%20have%20an%20end%20time%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20service%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FmunLabel)). For example, the municipality [Almelo](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q988) has its coordinates ([`P625`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P625)), and parent place ([`P131`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P131)) erroneously missing in the results:

```
SELECT ?mun ?munLabel ?coords ?parentPlace ?area WHERE {
  ?mun p:P31 ?instanceOf # Get statement because we need this later
       .
  ?instanceOf ps:P31/wdt:279* wd:Q2039348.
  
  OPTIONAL {
    ?mun wdt:P625 ?coords;
      wdt:P131 ?parentPlace; 
      wdt:P2046 ?area
      .
  }
  
  MINUS { ?instanceOf pq:P582 ?endTime. } # Don't show municipalities that have an end time
  
  service wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} ORDER BY ?munLabel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using one `OPTIONAL` statement instead of 3 separately.
In this case, Almelo doesn't have an 'area', `wdt:P2046`, so the whole `OPTIONAL` statement evaluates as false, and so it binds no variables.

The following query works:
Notice that we have 3 distinct optional statements, so that they may fail to bind variables independently of each other.

```
SELECT ?mun ?munLabel ?coords ?parentPlace ?area WHERE {
  ?mun p:P31 ?instanceOf # Get statement because we need this later
       .
  ?instanceOf ps:P31/wdt:279* wd:Q2039348.
  
  OPTIONAL {?mun wdt:P625 ?coords }
  OPTIONAL {?mun wdt:P131 ?parentPlace }
  OPTIONAL {?mun wdt:P2046 ?area }

  
  MINUS { ?instanceOf pq:P582 ?endTime. } # Don't show municipalities that have an end time
  
  service wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} ORDER BY ?munLabel
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `OPTIONAL` each statement independently:

```
  OPTIONAL { ?mun wdt:P625 ?coords . }
  OPTIONAL { ?mun wdt:P131 ?parentPlace . }
  OPTIONAL { ?mun wdt:P2046 ?area . }
```

Otherwise, if one of them is missing, then the whole `OPTIONAL` block is ignored.

See also [Multiple Optional Graph Patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#MultipleOptionals).